# Terminology question in Dixmier's C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

On page 33, we have that if $K$ is a closed subspace of some hilbert space $H$, he uses the symbol $H\bigoplus K$, except instead of a $+$ sign it is just a $-$ sign.  I cannot find anywhere what the latex command for this symbol is as I've never seen it.  At first I thought it stood for H/K, the quotient space, but in the section on quotient spaces he actually uses the / symbol.  However, that was with respect to an algebra A and not a vector space.

My only other idea would be perhaps $K^\perp$, i.e. everything perpendicular to $K$.

Edit: Was asking what $H\ominus K$ stood for, and it is $K^\perp$.

Comment: Okay I'm pretty sure it's $K^\perp$ based on the few sentences below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LaTex symbol is $\ominus$, typed \ominus; personally, by the symbol $H\ominus K$ I mean the orthogonal complement of $K$ in $H$: the set of all $h\in H$ that are orthogonal to every $k\in K$ (i.e., $\langle h,k\rangle=0$ for every $k\in K$). But I refer to a different textbook ("Introductory Real Analysis", by Kolmogorov and Fomin, p. 157).

Comment: Yeah after some thought I realized this was the only thing that made sense, I'd just never seen it before and had no clue how to "say" it or what to search for in tex.  I suppose the $\perp$ symbol is more popular these days.  Thanks for the confirmation.